# Add Wireguard vpn to Ubuntu Network Settings

Tags: networking, vpn, settings, wireguard

I'm running Wireguard on pivpn on my raspberry pi 4. I mananged to add the client config file to my pc and I can access the vpn. Now I want to add the vpn to the Network settings in Ubuntu (see picture) so that I don't have to use the command line everytime I want to start it up. But I can't figure out how to add it, if it's possible.

If you need any more information you can ask for it, I don't know what I have to give.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin: https://github.com/max-moser/network-manager-wireguard for this. I installed it successfully with the readme of this fork:
https://github.com/madduci/network-manager-wireguard
but run into this issue:
https://github.com/max-moser/network-manager-wireguard/issues/62

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Currently it's the best answer I have and I think, it'll help people on the way, better than nothing. I'll gladly delete it, if someone posts a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command `nmcli connection import type wireguard file YourConfigFile.conf` via the comments of https://www.xmodulo.com/wireguard-vpn-network-manager-gui.html It works in Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu 22.04, too

Answer (score 0):

There is currently **no integration** with Network Manager and the Settings application and Wireguard.  Wireguard does not have a Network Manager plugin to handle it, and in fact requires other Kernel modules to be compiled in, such that it's not readily available on systems.

The only way to configure Wireguard is to do it manually with the wireguard utilities on the command line and with its configuration files - there is no GUI integration with Network Manager at this time.

(Note I am not familiar with GNOME Network Manager upstream, and do not know if Wireguard integration as a plugin is on the radar - that's something you'd have to talk to Network Manager upstream about)

Comment: I deleted my incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

WireGuard can be configured in `nm-connection-editor` (**Network Connections**) GUI. Just click the **`+`** button at the bottom left of the window, select **WireGuard** under **Virtual**, and fill in the data manually.

My `nm-connection-editor` version is:

```
$ dpkg -l network-manager-gnome | tail -n 1
ii  network-manager-gnome 1.28.0-1ubuntu1 amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
```

My Ubuntu version is 22.10.

Support for WireGuard in **GNOME Settings** is expected in GNOME 44 to be shipped with Ubuntu 23.04.