# Configuring wireguard as a clinet using pre-existing conf file

Tags: vpn, configuration, wireguard

I'm a Linux/ubuntu newbie. searching web and doing the instructions did not solve my problem.
i used wireguard in MS windows using pre-existing conf file (which I downloaded from somewhere) and they worked just right. Now I installed wireguard and tried configuring it  on ubuntu but I don't know how to "import" those pre-existing conf files. I tried copying their content to `wg0.conf` and replaced the private key with the private key I got using `wg genkey`.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250870/add-wireguard-vpn-to-ubuntu-network-settings/1250922#1250922.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Wireguard vpn to Ubuntu Network Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250870/add-wireguard-vpn-to-ubuntu-network-settings)

Comment: @EliahKagan sadly no. my file is a .conf file and it's far different from an .ovpn file